# Low Cost andd Urgent H Bridge Need?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, h-bridge, esp32

I am Creating a H Bridge for 4 x 12V 5A BDC Motor with driving ESP32 Digital Output.

Do I need any Components? because I Must be Small PCB design.
(Maybe I can place 1k Resistor to N Channel MOSFET Gate-Source)

[image]

I am Sorry to say (BLDC) it.I Have 4 BDC Motor.

and I Re Upload the Schematics.

maybe I can Place the Bulk Cap(1000uF 25V)
[image]

Comment: Your design is going to suffer from significant current shoot-through. Please google what I refer to because it will be quite problematic to you.

Comment: "Urgent" is your problem, not ours. Its irrelevant to the question.

Comment: First of all, you do not drive a brushless motor with an H-bridge.

Comment: @DKNguyen isnt Dangerous for MCU?

Comment: Not driving a motor with an H-bridge does not mean driving it directly from an MCU. There are more ways to drive motors than just H-bridges and H-bridges can't drive every kind of motor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The circuit you have posted will blow up, not control a BLDC motor.

Things you absolutely need for your circuit to move a BLDC motor and not catch fire:

1. You need to have independent control of each gate to avoid shoot through, or at minimum some mechanism to inject dead time (or your mosfets will just fail).
2. A BLDC motor has 3 phases, not 2. You need another half bridge phase.
3. You need to employ some kind of technique measure the angle of the rotor relative to the stator (this is basically the core problem of BLDC motor control).
4. You need bypass capacitors to prevent the power supply ripple produced by the motor.

Things you really *should* do that aren't fundamentally necessary:

1. You probably should not use PMOS, but instead use the same NMOS transistor everywhere, and use a half bridge driver for gate management.
2. You probably also want to make sure you put dedicated *complementary* PWM (if the ESP32 supports that) on each half bridge instead of just GPIO.